# Why can not I use the "keypress" event for the "p" key?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm not getting anything on the console, doing what it is doing below:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
        const key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if(key === 80) // Key "p"
            console.log("p");
});
```

Comment: do you have CAPS-LOCK on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`80` is a `P`, you have to hold down the shift key.

`p` is `112`.

You could have figured this out if you had `console.log(key)`.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
 const key = e.key || e.which;
 if (key === 'p' || key === 112) {
   console.log("p");
 }
});
```